# is this a bad habit when using a database call?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, tornado

i'm using tornado for its simplicity, and am using it with Pymongo, so because i hear always about asynchronous calls, to serve lot of clients, then, i was asking, what is really an asynchronous calls to a database, so this code for example:

for example, suppose a page where a user have 4 areas where to search, so the result will be a 4 results.

```
A = calls the database to search for an element a.
B = calls the database to search for an element b.
C = calls the database to search for an element c.
D = calls the database to search for an element d.
then render a pages where a user will see the results (a,b,c,d)
```

so, this will be a killer for the server, since he must stay for all the 4 requests to finish, or do it serve the first result and then wait even if the database calls are blocking and make a bucket where he joins all the results to be served to the client? or the split of the 4 operations must be done with asynchronous database library (like Motor or Asyncmongo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to PyMongo will block Tornado's IOLoop and prevent further processing of any client HTTP request until the PyMongo method completes.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#does-pymongo-support-asynchronous-frameworks-like-gevent-tornado-or-twisted

Comment: so the time from finding "a" till the render the template will be blocked, and not freeing ressources when a is found, then b, then c ... and group them in bucket and render?

Comment: Yes. Therefore, make sure all your Mongo queries are very fast.

Comment: so i think i'll stick with Motor, hope i could understand it :(